# Software sources crashes

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, software-sources

Software sources crashes
when I run it from terminal I get this error:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk 
             Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 38, in <module>
        from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 45, in <module>
        from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 53, in <module>
        from ppa import AddPPASigningKeyThread, expand_ppa_line
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 31, in <module>
        import pycurl
    ImportError: librtmp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    [1]+  Stopped                 sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Just upgraded the distribution, it seems like it is broken in some way.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get remove --reinstall software-properties-gtk`

Answer (score 1):

Your output explains everything: it can't find the librtmp.so.0 library. You have to install the package providing that file with:

```
sudo apt-get install librtmp0
```

Comment: And probably file a bug on the `software-properties-gtk`, no? I mean the package dependencies would be supposed to handle that ...